# How to optimize RXJS operator to avoid messy code?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to avoid messy code using RXjs. There is a following code:

```typescript
combineLatest([
  this.usersService.userRightsObs$,
  this.layersService.flatLayersObs$,
])
.pipe(debounceTime(300))
.subscribe(([userRights, treeLayers]) => {
  const editableLayers = userRights.editableLayers.map((layerId) => {
    return treeLayers.get(layerId.toString());
  });
  this.layersService.setEditableLayers(editableLayers);
});
```

So, I dislike that my code look messy in this place:

```typescript
const editableLayers = userRights.editableLayers.map((layerId) => {
  return treeLayers.get(layerId.toString());
});
    
this.layersService.setEditableLayers(editableLayers);
```

I think it is not responsible place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to the StackOverflow. In your case, there's not much to upgrade, really. You can move mapping to the operator and use anonymous functions to shorten the code though.

```typescript
combineLatest([
  this.usersService.userRightsObs$,
  this.layersService.flatLayersObs$,
])
.pipe(
  debounceTime(300)
  map(([userRights, treeLayers]) => userRights.editableLayers.map((layerId) => treeLayers.get(layerId.toString()))
)
.subscribe(editableLayers => {
  this.layersService.setEditableLayers(editableLayers);
});
```

Comment: Your code imo better as it highlights the only `sideeffect` that happens in this block and makes transformations explizit (via `map`).